# Contagens condicionadas a grupos utilizando geom_hex

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suponha que eu tenho um conjunto de dados com três variáveis, sendo duas numéricas e uma categórica. Eu quero criar uma visualização para ele utilizando `geom_hex`, de modo a visualizar a relação entre as duas variáveis numéricas e a densidade de observações em cada região do gráfico. Essa é uma tarefa trivial, como podemos ver abaixo:

```r
set.seed(1)

n <- 10000

x <- rnorm(n)
y <- x + rnorm(n)

dados <- data.frame(x, y, grupo = rep(c("a", "b"), c(0.8*n, 0.2*n)))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dados, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_hex() +
  facet_wrap(~ grupo)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Entretanto, os grupos `a` e `b` são desbalanceados. No meu exemplo, 80% das observações estão no grupo `a` e os restantes 20% estão no grupo `b`. Com isso, fica bastante difícil perceber como está a densidade de pontos para o grupo `b`, pois a legenda das contagens considera a concentração geral de pontos para ser determinada.

Como eu poderia criar uma visualização, possivelmente com duas legendas de contagens, para que ambas as densidades pudessem ser melhor percebidas? Ou o melhor seria criar dois gráficos separados e juntá-los posteriormente?

O primeiro tipo de solução me agrada mais, pois gostaria que ele fosse generalizável para variáveis categóricas com mais de dois níveis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3 ideias, cada uma com vantagens e desvantagens. Modifiquei seu exemplo para conter 3 grupos:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 9000
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- x + rnorm(n)
dados <- data.frame(x, y, grupo = rep(letters[1:3], c(0.6*n, 0.3*n, 0.1*n)))
```

### 1. Escalas separadas por grupo

Ideia: usar `lapply` para gerar *plots* separados para cada grupo e montar o gráfico com `gridExtra`, `ggpubr` ou pacotes semelhantes.

Vantagem: cada plot é otimizado para a extensão de cada grupo.

Desvantagem: é difícil comparar os grupos quando cada um está com uma escala diferente.

```
hplot <- function(g) {
  ggplot(subset(dados, grupo == g), aes(x, y)) +
    geom_hex() +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = range(dados$x)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = range(dados$y)) +
    facet_wrap(~ grupo) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
}

plista <- lapply(unique(dados$grupo), hplot)

gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = plista, nrow = 1)
# ou
ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = plista, nrow= 1)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 2. Escala de cor multi tonal

Ideia: usar uma escala de cor com ampla variação de tonalidades, para ressaltar pequenas diferenças. Usei o pacote `colorspace` para gerar a paleta.

Vantagem: fácil de comparar visualmente cada grupo.

Desvantagem: é impossível criar uma paleta adequada para cegueira de cores com grande amplitude de tons.

```
library(colorspace)

p <- ggplot(dados, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_hex() +
  facet_wrap(~ grupo)

pal <- sequential_hcl(128, h = c(-128, 360), c = c(34, 42, 24), l = c(24, 82))
p + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = pal)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 3. Escala de cor logarítmica

Ideia: usar uma escala de cor logarítmica, para ressaltar diferenças entre valores mais baixos. Usei o pacote `colorspace` para gerar a paleta, usando a opção `power`.

Vantagem: pode-se usar uma paleta adequada para cegueira de cores (não apenas na variação de tons, mas nas de croma e luminância).

Desvantagem: mais difícil de interpretar; ressalta diferenças entre valores pequenos mas atenua diferenças entre valores altos.

```
pal2 <- sequential_hcl(128, h = c(-82, -8), c = c(56, 36), l = c(24, 80), power = 2)

p + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = pal2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A solução 1 é excelente. Vai bem em linha com aquilo que eu idealizava, mas não estava sabendo como implementar.